# "Used to go" vs. "attended" — which one is correct here?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, simple-past

> I attended x institute for almost ten years. Last year I completed an advanced book entitled *Landmark*. Taking the advice of one of my teachers, I enrolled at another institute for a teacher training course.
>
> I used to go x institute for almost ten years. Last year I competed an advanced book entitled *Landmark*. Taking the advice of one of my teachers, I enrolled at another institute for a teacher training course.

Which version is better?

Comment: The verb 'go' is rarely transitive. You certainly can't 'go an institute'. 'Go to' and 'attend' are synonymous (have usages conveying the same sense). This does not mean they are _always_ interchangeable, though they are here. Actually, the temporal ('for almost ten years' requires 'I went to').

Comment: I.e, the second example is ungrammatical, but the first is OK. You can't use _used to_ with a durative temporal expression using _for_, as @EdwinAshworth points out.

Comment: Replace "used to go" with "went to" if you want to use the verb *go* in there.  "I went to Belgrade Institute for almost ten years."

Comment: @John, surely not ungrammatical—just temporally quite problematical in this case. “I used to go to school for three hours every morning” is perfectly fine, but of course, to make a ‘habit’ out of doing something for ten whole years, one would have to be _very_ old.

Comment: As you prefer; I would award a ?*, personally.

Answer (score 1):

The first is better, though there is some lack of cohesion between the ideas presented.

Suggested minor tweaks:

> I attended x institute for nearly ten years. Then last year, after
>   reading a book entitled "Landmark" and following the advice of one of
>   my teachers, I enrolled at another institute to attend a teacher
>   training course.

Notes:

- "advanced book" is somewhat meaningless and can be effectively reduced to just "book" unless you provide additional context. What was advanced about it? Difficult to read, etc.
- Use of the word "Then" to start the next sentence provides sequence
- Merging of reading the book and following the advice, allows the reader to flow to the next primary action - enrolling at another institute

Comment: http://www.landmarkworldwide.com/after-the-landmark-forum/advanced-programs/advanced-course